# Getting UnicodeEncodeError when trying to read a JSON string from a request text

Tags: python, json, encoding

I am learning python3 and I am currently working in a little project which involves web scraping and the JSON module.
My script gets a string of json data and when I try to load it with the json module I get the following error:

*UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010c' in position 1: character maps to .*

I am able to print the string but not to load it with json.loads

The code is:

```
jsonData = json.loads(r.text)
pprint.pprint(jsonData)
```

while the r.text where it fails is:

`{'event': {'sport': {'name': 'Tennis', 'homePlayer': 'Nadal', 'awayPlayer': '\u010cili\u0107'} ...`

How can I avoid this error? I have been trying to encode with utf-8 but I get the same result. If the value of the dictionary of key "awayPlayer" is "\u010cili\u0107" or similar instead of "Cilic" (which is the true name of the awayPlayer) it would be fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The question does not contain sufficient a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Therefore, it's hard to guess content and encoding of input file as well as what is `r` (and maybe more unclear issues).

Let's suppose that there is `"awayPlayer": "\u010cili\\u0107"` in `r.text` (note number of backslashes in `\u010c` vs. `\\u0107`):

```
import json
import pprint

fileData = '{"event": {"sport": {"name": "Tennis", "homePlayer": "Nadal", "awayPlayer": "\u010cili\\u0107"}}}'
jsonData = json.loads(fileData)

print('\n   print(fileData), pprint.pprint(fileData):')
print(fileData)
# print(repr(fileData)) # debugging
pprint.pprint(fileData)

print('\n   print(jsonData), pprint.pprint(jsonData):')
pprint.pprint(jsonData)
# print(jsonData['event']['sport']['awayPlayer']) # debugging
```

**Output** does not reproduce any issue: `58259849.py`

```
   print(fileData), pprint.pprint(fileData):
{"event": {"sport": {"name": "Tennis", "homePlayer": "Nadal", "awayPlayer": "Čili\u0107"}}}
('{"event": {"sport": {"name": "Tennis", "homePlayer": "Nadal", "awayPlayer": '
 '"Čili\\u0107"}}}')

   print(jsonData), pprint.pprint(jsonData):
{'event': {'sport': {'name': 'Tennis', 'homePlayer': 'Nadal', 'awayPlayer': 'Čilić'}}}
{'event': {'sport': {'awayPlayer': 'Čilić',
                     'homePlayer': 'Nadal',
                     'name': 'Tennis'}}}
```